# VBA - Copy first line of text in rectangle shape

Tags: vba, excel

Unfortunatly all the solutions i found for this didn´t helped me.

In my Workbook i have a Shape with text. With a CommandButton i would like to change the second text line, the first line should stay the same.

I only found a way to copy the whole text from the shape, but i just want to copy the first line.

This is my Code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Shape
    Dim Headline As String

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("WKA_1")

    ' Try to copy first line:
    Headline = Sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text  ' Copy whole text

    Sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Headline & vbCrLf & "Process: " & UserForm1.Label57 & "%"

End Sub
```

I really hope someone can help me with that.

**EDIT:**

In the Picture you can see my shapes. With the Button "Add_Assignment" the second Shape is added to the worksheet. Also the first line of the text will be added to the shape like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Shape

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("WKA_1")
    With Sh.TextFrame
        .Characters.Text = Add_Assignment.TextBox1 & ", " & Add_Assignment.TextBox2
        .HorizontalAlignment = msoAlignCenter
        .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The Second Line of text will be added and change with the Button "Add Workpackage"

[image]

Comment: Are there line breaks between your lines or are they wrapped?

Comment: @Sam see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex depending on what the line break is determined by.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sh As Shape, Headline As String

    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("WKA_1")

    Headline = Sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Headline = GetFirstLine(Headline)

    Debug.Print Headline
    'Sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Headline

End Sub

Public Function GetFirstLine(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "^(.*)$"
        If .TEST(inputString) Then
            GetFirstLine = .Execute(inputString)(0)
        Else
            GetFirstLine = inputString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/cY7Hy6/1/).

---

Regex:

`^` asserts position at start of a line

1st Capturing Group `(.*)`

`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as 
possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`$` asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: Did you try this?